# Spring @Transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

Im having a hard time understanding how to decide what methods to annotate with Spring @Transaction.

```
BankService {

    transfer(Account from, Account to, int amount){
        deduct(from, amount);
        deposit(to, amount);
    }

    deduct(Account account, int amount){
        account = accountRepo.load(account); //make sure we dont have an old reference with old balance            
        int balance = account.getBalance();
        if (balance<amount){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not enough money");
        } else {
            account.setBalance(balance-amount);
            accountRepo.save(account);
        }
    }

    deposit(Account account, int amount){
        account = accountRepo.load(account); //make sure we dont have an old reference with old balance
        account.setBalance(account.getBalance() + amount);
        accountRepo.save(account);
    }

}
```

Within a transfer, if the deduct fails, obviously the deposit should *not* be persisted even if the deposit doesnt fail.

Out of the five methods (transfer, deduct, deposit, load, save), which ones should be annotated with @Transactional and why?

Comment: Try to throw the most helpful exceptions possible. In this case, if the account would be overdrawn, an `IllegalStateException` is more descriptive than a plain `RuntimeException`.

Comment: i think this will help http://javaidm.blogspot.in/2016/02/how-transaction-is-managed-in-spring.html

Answer (score 4):

**General answer**

Look for the operations that define actual transactions--in this case, the `transfer` method. This method represents a complete transaction in its own right, and so you should mark it

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)
```

You need to protect the other methods from being called erroneously out of a transaction, and so it's a good idea to annotate them

```
@Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY)
```

to ensure that they're only called from the context of some running transaction.

**Spring-specific answer**

By default, Spring uses proxy objects to implement advice such as transactions, and *self-calls* (methods invoked on `this`, either implicitly or explicitly, that don't go through the proxy object) don't have advice applied. This means that Spring won't actually enforce the advice on the `deduct` and `deposit` methods in this case, although it would still protect them from being called outside a transaction by something else. The AspectJ AOP model requires an additional compile-time step but avoids the self-call problem and correctly applies advice to all method calls.

Comment: So the transfer method should be annotated with @Tr...(propagation = REQUIRED) and *all* the remaining four methods should be annotated with @(Tr...propagation = MANDATORY)? Some people (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300683/794779) say CRUD methods should *not* be annotated with @Transactional, what is your take on that? Also, if the deduct and deposit methods are annotated but not enforced, doesnt that mean trouble? Arguably annotated methods are expected to be enforced, no?

Comment: @fred The answer you linked to is incomplete at best. The author was saying that you shouldn't permit a transaction to open on random CRUD methods, which is accurate; `MANDATORY` tells Spring to throw an exception if the method is called outside a transaction rather than to just process it. Even if you're using Spring proxy AOP (which I don't), using `MANDATORY` (1) serves as documentation and (2) provides some protection against external classes' calling `deduct` directly.

Comment: @fred Also, you haven't posted `load` and `save`, and it's not obvious what they do. I'm only talking about `transfer`, `deposit`, and `deduct`.

Comment: Assume the CRUD methods are from the org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

EDIT: previously linked to the wrong class!

Comment: So annotating deduct and deposit with mandatory protects them from being called outside of a transaction if the call comes from outside this service class, but its still possible that non-transaction annotated methods within this service class can call them because then the annotation isnt enforced?

Comment: @fred If you use proxy AOP, potentially. With proxy AOP, there's no mechanism for enforcing an existing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Every method that is modifying 2+ properties should be @Transactional. I was about to give you as example the transfer money method, even if you didn't have it.

Comment: I was under the impression that its not the number of properties modified but the nature of the operations performed that determined whether methods should be annotated with @Transactional or not.

Comment: Think what happens in the database. You need to change 2+ things ? You should rollback for one fail? Knowing that, it is easy to see the Transactional methods.

Comment: Sure, you should roll back for a single failure. You need to learn about isolation levels, especially repeatable-read.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I see, that is less ambiguous and confusing. But still, e.g. the deduct and deposit methods only *change* one thing, but they still *do* two things (first load to make sure we dont have an old reference with old balance, then change the balance and save the account). To me it seems that constitutes reason to annotate them too?