# Hibernate+Spring SessionFactory configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

What is the right way to configure SessionFactory?

If I do it this way:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:packagesToScan="ua.com.javer.flowerexpert"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

I get this error:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

And if I change to `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:packagesToScan="ua.com.javer.flowerexpert"/>
```

I get:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
```

Even though in some older project `hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` works fine.

My `pom.xml` contains:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's my **Service** class:

```
@Service("colorsService")
@Transactional
public class ColorsService {
@Autowired
private ColorDao colorDao;

public List<Color> getAllColors() {
    return colorDao.getAllColors();
}
}
```

And here's the **DAO**:

```
@Component
@Repository("colorDao")
public class ColorDaoHibernate implements ColorDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public ColorDaoHibernate() {
}

@Override
public List<Color> getAllColors() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
// StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Color");
    return  query.list();
}
}
```

**NOTICE:**

If I use `sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();` in DAO class `hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` in session configuration would not cause a problem.

But the point is - I want to use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK, problem solved!**

In my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` I've had:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.com.javer.flowerexpert" />
```

At the same time I had:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.com.javer.flowerexpert.dao"/>
```

in `dao-context.xml`, so the `ua.com.javer.flowerexpert.dao` package was scanned twice.

I've changed packages to scan in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` to:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.com.javer.flowerexpert.controller" />
```

to scan `ua.com.javer.flowerexpert.controller` package only (and not dao). Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you enabled the [transaction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) support in your spring configuration file. If not, enable it using `<tx:annotation-driven>`

And also, declare the `transactionManager` as follows:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Try removing `@Transactional` from `ColorsService` as below:

```
@Service("colorsService")
public class ColorsService {
@Autowired
private ColorDao colorDao;

public List<Color> getAllColors() {
    return colorDao.getAllColors();
}
}
```

And adding it to `ColorDaoHibernate`:

```
@Repository("colorDao")
public class ColorDaoHibernate implements ColorDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public ColorDaoHibernate() {
}
@Transactional
@Override
public List<Color> getAllColors() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
// StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Color");
    return  query.list();
}
}
```

Edit `sessionFactory` bean definition as below:

```
<bean id="hibernateProps"
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
                <property name="properties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
                p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="ua.com.javer.flowerexpert"
                p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProps" />
```

Comment: Added hibernateProps - got a new exception: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction`

Comment: BTW, it's told [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300683/4685486), that @Transctional annotation should be placed on Service methods, not DAO methods.

Comment: One thing to make sure, you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your spring configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I've got <mvc:annotation-driven /> in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Comment: Thank you, @Arpit! Problem solved. Will give the answer now